# IIS Shared Configuration Share for Cluster FTP Service on Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008, ftp, iis-7.5, cluster, failovercluster

Microsoft gives the following order for setting up the Clustered FTP (after installing IIS, FTP Service, and setting up your Cluster):

1. Set up a file share that will be used for IIS Shared Configuration.
2. Configure IIS Shared Configuration on all cluster nodes.
3. Configure Offline Files for IIS Shared Configuration on all cluster nodes.
4. Configure the FTP site and specify the location of its content on one cluster node.
5. Configure highly availability for your FTP site by creating a generic script in Failover Clustering.

However, I'd like to store the IIS Shared Configuration information on the machine name and storage I'm using for the FTP.  This means I'd have to configure the cluster service first with the ip, machine name, and storage before starting the first step (configuring the cluster service is step 5.)

Has anyone done this?  Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is indeed possible.  Create your Cluster Service/Application as a File Server with the name, IP address and storage you want.  Setup the share for the IIS Shared Configuration.  At this point, start the steps to setup the Cluster FTP Service, however for the last step, simply add a 'Generic Script' resource to the Service/Application you have already setup.  Set up the dependencies so that clusftp7 resource depends on all the other parts of the Cluster Service before it comes online.